# Automatically change Page after 10 Seconds (ASP Classic)

Tags: asp-classic

I have an Active Server Page, which displays Booking of the current Day. I setted the PageSize to two, so my display is displaying just 2 bookings per side, if there are more Records.
So actually i have 8 bookings in my Recordset, so my ASP creates 4 Pages.

To illustrate it, i have done a snapshot.

[Display](http://i46.tinypic.com/351j2bk.png)

As you can see, there are 4 Pages and i can switch between them. With `>` i get the next two bookings and with `<` i can get the previous two bookings.

What i need desperately is a automatically Change of the pages in 10 second intervall.
For Example:  Display the first page for 10 seconds, then switch to the next page and display it for 10 seconds and so on. If the last Page has been reached, then start again from the first page.

I think i need something like a Timer which changes the Page every 10 seconds and a loop which starts from the first page again if the last has been reached. But i don't know how to do that.

I would be glad if someone could help me.

Part of my Code so far:

```
Option Explicit
'declare variables
Dim Currpage, pageLen, lastNumber, PageRem, PageTen
Dim connection, recordset, sSQL, sConnString, next10, prev10, P
Dim RSPrevPage, RSNextPage, start
Dim thema, rsRaum, displayanzeige, bstatus, raum_id, GebaeudeBezeichnung, HinweisText, KOPPELBESTUHLUNG_ID, raumname
'Get the current page the user is on, if it's the first time they
'visit and the variable 'PageNo' is empty, then 'CurrPage' gets set to 1
'Else the current page variable 'CurrPage' is set to the page number requested
If IsEmpty(Request.Querystring("PageNo")) then
CurrPage = 1
Else
CurrPage = Cint(Request.Querystring("PageNo"))
End If

'the two functions below return the next 10 and prev 10 page number
Function getNext10(num)
pageLen = len(num)
If pageLen = 1 Then
next10 = 10
ElseIf pageLen>1 Then
pageRem = 10
pageTen = right(num, 1)
next10 = num + pageRem - pageTen
End If
getNext10 = next10
End Function

Function getPrev10(num)
pageLen = len(num)
If pageLen = 1 then
prev10 = 1
ElseIf pageLen>1 then
lastNumber = right(num, 1)
prev10 = num - lastNumber - 10
End If
If prev10 = 0 then
prev10 = 1
End If
getPrev10 = prev10
End Function


 Do Until Recordset.AbsolutePage <> CurrPage OR Recordset.Eof


 Recordset.MoveNext
 Loop


'the next 2 lines setup the page number for the "previous" and "next" links
RSNextPage = CurrPage + 1
RSPrevPage = CurrPage -1

'find out the number of pages returned in the recordset
'if the Next10 page number is greater than the recordset page count
'then set Next10 to the recordset pagecount
If Next10 > Recordset.PageCount Then
Next10 = Recordset.PageCount
End If

'the variable start determines where to start the page number navigation
' i.e. 1, 10, 20, 30 and so on. 
If prev10 = 1 AND next10 - 1 < 10 Then
start = 1
Else
start = Next10 - 10
If right(start, 1) > 0 Then
start = replace(start, right(start, 1), "0")
start = start + 10
End If
End If

'This checks to make sure that there is more than one page of results
If Recordset.PageCount > 1 Then
'Work out whether to show the Previous 10 '<<' 
If currpage > 1 Then
response.write("<a href=""paging.asp?PageNo=" & Prev10 & """><<</a> ")
End If
'Work out whether to show the Previous link '<' 
If NOT RSPrevPage = 0 then
response.write("<a href=""paging.asp?PageNo=" & RSPrevPage & """><</a> ")
End If

'Loop through the page number navigation using P as our loopcounter variable 
For P = start to Next10

If NOT P = CurrPage then
response.write("<a href=""paging.asp?PageNo=" & P & """>" & P & "</a> ")
Else
'Don't hyperlink the current page number 
response.write(" <b>" & P & " </b>")
End If
Next
'this does the same as the "previous" link, but for the "next" link
If NOT RSNextPage > Recordset.PageCount Then
response.write("<a href=""paging.asp?PageNo=" & RSNextPage & """>></a> ")
End If

'Work out whether to show the Next 10 '>>' 
If NOT Next10 = Recordset.PageCount Then
response.write(" <a href=""paging.asp?PageNo=" & Next10 & """>>></a>")
End If
```

Comment: @jjj that's a **terrible** solution, putting aside that the post here is about classic ASP which doesn't have this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Meta Refresh](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H76) like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10;URL=nextPage.asp" />
```

The ***10*** in the `content` is the number of seconds followed by a `;` and then the `URL=<url>`.
This is a regular HTML tag that you should put in your `<HEAD>`. The URL itself you can modify via ASP.

Comment: Thanks, but i dont know how to increment the pages. Because my URL is: paging.asp?PageNo=1 for the first page and paging.asp?PageNo=2 for the second page and so on

Comment: Well then, just call your function and put the result in the URL:  `URL=paging.asp?PageNo=<% Response.Write(getNext10(num))%>`

Comment: Ok thanks, its working so far, but now another Problem. If the last Page has reached he is still incrementing the PageNo. He should start from the beginning if the last page has been reached. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Yes, that *again* is logic you should put in your getNext10 function. If it passes the maximum - return 0

Comment: @Paks - You should notice that with that logic, it will loop forever... I'm not sure if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Yeah iam trying to do something like: If Currentpage > Pagecount Then set currentpage to 1, but working not yet

Answer (score 0):

In the last section (where you are already deciding whether or not to put a "next" link), go ahead and use ASP to write a script tag to call a javascript function:

```
(from the last section of your code example above)
'Work out whether to show the Next 10 '>>' 
If NOT Next10 = Recordset.PageCount Then
    response.write(" <a href=""paging.asp?PageNo=" & Next10 & """>>></a>")
    response.write("<script type=""text/javascript"" language=""javascript"">goToNextPage(" & Next10 & """);</script>")
End If
```

This will cause the page to call a javascript function "goToNextPage(pageNumber);" that will accept the Next10 value. Because you are writing this script tag to the output stream only when already writing a "next" link, it will also only get called when there is another page to display.

Then in your HEAD section you would add the javascript function to handle the request:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
/*
This function accepts the requested page number and then waits 10 seconds before redirecting back to itself with the new "pageNo" value in the query string
*/
function goToNextPage(nextPageNumber)
{
    setTimeout(function(){window.location='paging.asp?pageNo='+nextPageNumber;},10000);
}

</script>
</head>
```